# What could cause a program to not read an entire file?

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

I have a program that should read from a file.It reads some amount of data but not all.When i try to read the same file at the same location with another program done in the same manner with the same classes it reads the entire file.
Here is the code used in both programs:

```
                if (i >= 1) {
                try {

                file = new File("Tabel " + i + " " + timeLine + ".csv");
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.write(FileChooserSave.getInstance().getStringArray()[i]);
                if (i == 1) {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    isr.close();
                    br.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

It always stops reading in the same place.I checked to see if there is some ackward character but there isn't.
I should also mention that the file from which i read is in the .csv format and is a pretty big one, but i don' see if that is the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "another program done in the same manner with the same classes"? And do you get any errors in your log?

Comment: What i mean by another program is an entire new project made with identical code that reads the exact same file in the exact same location.At first i tought that the blame belongs to the name of the variables but i checked that multiple times.Not the variables name are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file while the FileWriter is still open.  This can lead to not having all the writes flushed to disk.

Try to move the call to close before new FileInputStream.

Comment: I realized that.After i called flush everything worked just fine.Anyway thank you very much for your answer!:)

Answer (score 3):

Hm... Your solution is a bit overcomplicated, so there might be quite a lot of things causing the problem.

I'd try launching the application in debug mode and when it *"hangs"* simply pause the thread e.g. in Eclipse, and you will see where it is waiting for data.

If you are using Java 7, there is a simple command that may help you reading all the lines of a file at once:

```
Path file = Paths.get(filename);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
```